# Magento2 Backup disabled

Tags: magento2

Magento Version 2.2.7.

I wanted to backup the system and database with the Tools given by Magento2.

But in the backend when I go to System - Backups, I get the message

> Backup functionality is disabled
>
> Backup functionality is currently disabled. Please use other means for backups

Where can i enable it?

Answer (score 29):

You can enable Backup setting by going to Stores/Configuration, Advanced=>System, Backup Setting:

[image]

If you want to enable it with the CLI, you can use the command:

```
php bin/magento config:set system/backup/functionality_enabled 1
```

Comment: if you do auto backups, where are they put?

Comment: @sammsft I believe they are put in /var/backup (where root directory is Magento, not system root).

Answer (score 6):

For the enable Backups to run below command.

> php bin/magento config:set system/backup/functionality_enabled 1

Answer (score -5):

Configuration - System - Backup Settings

vas